# Start main activity when opening backgrounded app from other app by url scheme

Tags: android, android-activity, deep-linking

I've just implemented deep linking to my app. I've added intent filter to my main activity. When user starts my url scheme I'm parsing it and handling in the activity to display proper information depending on parameters. It works well when my app is started from scratch.

```xml
    <activity
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:name="com.my.app.ui.activities.MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="myapp-scheme"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The problem occurs when user opens some other activities on stack and goes background. Now if this app is resumed from background by calling my scheme url, all activities are still on the stack and the main activity doesn't show up.
How can I resolve this?
I think about navigating back to the main activity, but I don't have info if app was started from other app or in the normal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your *MainActivity* as singleTask by adding following line in the manifest(for ManiActivity):

android:launchMode="singleTask"

Then, override the *onNewIntent()* in the *MainActivity* and handle the navigation based on deep link data.Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was searching for. :)

Comment: How can this be the right answer? If you look at the manfest that is posted in the question, OP already has specified `launchMode="singleTask"`!

Comment: Also, this can't be right because if the existing task already has another `Activity` on top of `MainActivity`, `MainActivity.onNewIntent()` will NOT be called.